# Find and Replace one character in the middle in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I am trying to find and replace an arrangement of 6 letters\special character\numbers.
For example they appear as such in my original code

```
DEVICE_NAME","CB2_02 DEVICE, DEVICE_NAME","CB3_09 DEVICE, DEVICE_NAME","OB6_12 DEVICE...
```

The order in which the letters, numbers, and special character appear are always the same.  I need to replace the `_` (underscore) between `CB3_09` with a `-` (hyphen).

I can easily find what I need using:

```
DEVICE_NAME","(.*_.*) (device)
```

but am having issues replacing the `_` with a `-`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use capture groups to capture this format as 2 parts (the part before the special character and the part after), and just replace the special character between them:

**Match:** `(DEVICE_NAME",".*?)_(.*? device)`

**Replace with:** `$1-$2`

Answer (score 1):

```
Search for:    `(DEVICE_NAME","[A-Z]{2}[0-9])_([0-9]{2} DEVICE)`
Replace with:  `\1-\2`
```

By being a little more specific with the search term you make sure you are replacing exactly what you want.